# Airbyte docker container not able to read local json file on MacOSX

Tags: json, data-engineering, etl

I am just trying to test out airbyte, I am loading up a json, I want to do some data manipulation and export it back out to json. All done locally with while running on docker.

```
Failed to load file:///tmp/airbyte_local/data_board.json: 
FileNotFoundError(2, ‘No such file or directory’) Traceback (most
recent call last): File “/airbyte/integration_code/source_file
/source.py”, line 101, in check with client.reader.open(): File
“/airbyte/integration_code/source_file/client.py”, line 86, in open
self._file = self._open() File “/airbyte/integration_code/source_file
/client.py”, line 130, in _open return smart_open.open(self.full_url,
**self.args) File “/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/smart_open
/smart_open_lib.py”, line 177, in open fobj = _shortcut_open( File 
“/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/smart_open
/smart_open_lib.py”, line 363, in _shortcut_open return
_builtin_open(local_path, mode, buffering=buffering, **open_kwargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
‘/tmp/airbyte_local/data_board.json’
```

A couple of things I've noticed/tried:

- this is the closest similar looking issue I've seen but the solution doesn't seem to be specific and it's more focused around the export than the import: https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/issues/1895
- https://discuss.airbyte.io/t/csv-file-source/1370/8 recommends you use `/tmp/airbyte_local`. when I did this on Mac it puts it in `/private/tmp/airbyte_local`. I've tried both as source directories and neither work
- I have added file sharing for `/private/tmp/airbyte_local`, it will not let me add it for `/tmp/airbyte_local`. you have to add via the `Favorites List` on Mac and that always maps to `private`
- seems like there are multiple `.env` files in the repo and I don't want to just start guessing and changing things

Question:
What additional setup needs to be done to run an file import → file export locally with docker ?
What attributes in what .env files need to be changed ?

```
Is this your first time deploying Airbyte?: No
OS Version / Instance: MacOS… a
Memory / Disk: 16 gb
Deployment: N/A running locally on docker
Airbyte Version: 0.40.17 (I pulled from the .env in the root of the cloned repo)
Source name/version: local
Destination name/version: local
Step: import of data
Description: not seeing file for import locally for docker
```

Comment: ever figure this out?